# Error in my Facebook Ad Set: Unsupported get request. Object with ID 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx' does not exist

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I simply want my Facebook ad to link to my Android app.

However I am getting this error in my Ad Set:

[image]

1. The objective of my campaign is 'App installs'
2. I've configured and linked the ad with my facebook developer app

[image]

3. The approved Facebook permissions are `user_birthday`, `user_gender`, `email` and `default`.

Is there anything I can do to fix this error? My ad just clicks through to my Android app (this works successfully when I test it in preview) however I'm still getting this error for some reason.

Any idea?

Comment: What is that what your first screenshot shows there - is that something from within the Facebook UI, or is that some kind of dashboard you are trying to create yourself?

Comment: That is showing in Facebook Ads Manager while I'm creating my Ad @CBroe

Comment: That sounds rather like a bug on Facebook’s end to me then. “Unsupported GET request” is usually what you get when you make API calls and try to access objects without having the necessary permissions - but you are not making any API calls yourself here, you are just using their dashboard. I’d try and file a bug report under https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs

Comment: Thanks I have just filed a bug from that page @CBroe

Answer (score 0):

go inside https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/
select you app and give access as "Get user Access Token" and generate it and use it for three months once your key generated copy that key and go inside app https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ add you key here you can see when your key will be expire and what permission this key have scroll down you will get extend your key access click on that and give your Facebook password your key will extend up to 90 days once and some permission are not expire